# Laravel Model can I implement

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Can I use implements on a model in laravel and if so how can I define a attribute in the $fillable array, If I can't use it with a variable I can just have a interface with a method *getBool()*?

I have two models both with a attribute in the fillable array called *bool* i would like to have a function that operation on both of these models.

So how can I create a interface class that I can implement on the models?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question maybe because of the lingo. However, `interface` is just a contract definition, it's not designed to add functionality per-se, just structure.

You could use a PHP traits to have shared code between models.

[PHP Traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)

Comment: Just told you why. Interfaces weren't made for code sharing per se. It was made to aid the SOLID principle. Traits were created for code sharing without extending many classes

Comment: I'm happy defining the operation multiple times within each model, and the interface class just defines the structure. I might be missing something i've never using interfaces or traits in PHP. I would like a function that says *toggleSetting(Setting $setting)* where Setting is the name of the interface, I can then upon a method that i know all settings have, getBool() defined in the interface, the getBool method may be different for every model.